# Removing the password field in woocommerce checkout page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, checkout, hook-woocommerce

I am trying to remove the password field in the checkout page.

Here is what I have tried *(code is in my `functions.php` theme file)*:

```
// Hook in
add_filter( 'woocommerce_default_address_fields' , 'custom_override_default_address_fields' );

// Our hooked in function - $address_fields is passed via the filter!
function custom_override_default_address_fields( $address_fields ) {
     $checkout_fields['account']['required'] = false;

     return $checkout_fields;
}
```

But it didn't work.

What is the hook for removing the password field in woocommerce checkout page?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> The hook **`woocommerce_default_address_fields`** is only used for default **address fields** and not for the account fields.

To make the passwords fields optional you should need using **`woocommerce_checkout_fields`** hook, this way:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields' , 'custom_override_checkout_fields' );
function custom_override_checkout_fields( $fields ) {
     // There is 2 password fields
     fields['account']['account_password']['required']  = false;
     fields['account']['account_password-2']['required'] = false;

     return $fields;
}
```

To remove those passwords fields you should need to use **`unset()`** PHP function this way:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields' , 'custom_override_checkout_fields' );
function custom_override_checkout_fields( $fields ) {
     unset($fields['account']['account_password']);
     unset($fields['account']['account_password-2']);

     return $fields;
}
```

> But I am not sure that is really possible, as it's something mandatory in WooCommerce checkout process, when you have enabled the option to register in checkout page…

*Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.*

---

**Official Reference:** [**Customizing checkout fields using actions and filters**](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/tutorial-customising-checkout-fields-using-actions-and-filters/)